# Instantiate overload not sure why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

So when I instantiated invaders it worked when i did 2 of them, but as soon as i tried to instantiate more than 2 (created a variable float `addInvaders`, and an if statement if `addInvader` is equal to 5) my game literally just crashes. It runs for a second, and I see it create like a million invaders then it Unity doesn't respond anymore. Wondering what I'm doing wrong, and what I can do to fix. I think this is all the code you need, please let me know I'll add additional code if need be.

```
//globals
float addInvader = 0f;
bool spawnInvader = true;
public GameObject invaders;


void Update()
{

    SpawnInvaders ();
    while (addInvader == 5f)
    {
        spawnInvader = false;
    }

}

void SpawnInvaders()
{
    if (spawnInvader) 
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        Quaternion roto = transform.rotation;


        newPos.x = 900f;
        newPos.y = 0f;
        newPos.z = 800f;
        roto.z = 180f;
        Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
        addInvader++;

        if (addInvader >= 1f)
        {
        newPos.x = newPos.x - 200f;
        newPos.y = 0f;
        newPos.z = 800f;
        roto.z = 180f;
        Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
        }
    }

    return;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll try to answer instead.

It appears you created an infinite loop :

```
while (addInvader == 5f)
{
    spawnInvader = false;
}
```

Change it to :

```
if (addInvader >= 5f)
{
    spawnInvader = false;
}
```

It should stop crashing.

Comment: thank you sir. will thumbs up when the time lets me. Stupid mistake on my part.